# CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler doesn't add error param to login page in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm trying to create a CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler in Spring boot to treat some cases where user is not allowed to authenticate even if his credentials are correct and display a custom error message.
I treat these cases in userDetailsServiceImp and I raise exception depending on the case.
the next step was to custom the AuthenticationFailureHandler.

Here is my CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler class :

```
 @Component
public class CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler {

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler.class);

@Override
public void onAuthenticationFailure(
        HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response,
        AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException {


        // Handle other authentication failures
    if (exception.getMessage().contains("example")) {
        super.setDefaultFailureUrl("/login?error=cause1");
    }

    else{
        super.setDefaultFailureUrl("/login?error=cause2");

    }



    super.onAuthenticationFailure(request, response, exception);


}
```

}

my security filter :

```
public SecurityFilterChain filterChainApp3(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authenticationProvider(myAuthenticationProvider());
http.cors().and().csrf().disable().
//conf ..

 .formLogin()
              .loginPage("/login")
              .permitAll().failureHandler(customFailure).
.successHandler(myAuthenticationSuccessHandler()).
and().logout().permitAll();
```

in the same security config class :

```
@Autowired

private CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler customFailure;
```

When I submit the auth form the login fails but I don't see param error in the URL.

**EDIT:**

Devtools after login form is submited : [image: Network]

the URL :http://localhost:8080/login

What is the problem and how can I solve it ?

Just a remarque, when I set a failureUrl in the security filter chaine the param is shown in the URL :

```
.permitAll().failureUrl("/login?error")
```

**EDIT2 :**
Spring Security logs :

```
  2023-09-30 22:40:31.012 DEBUG 22702 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : Loaded matching saved request http://localhost:8080/login?error=cause2
2023-09-30 22:40:31.015 DEBUG 22702 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2023-09-30 22:40:31.027 DEBUG 22702 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Failed to authorize filter invocation [GET /login?error=cause2] with attributes [hasRole('ROLE_USER')]
2023-09-30 22:40:31.034 DEBUG 22702 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : Saved request http://localhost:8080/login?error=cause2 to session
2023-09-30 22:40:31.034 DEBUG 22702 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy        : Redirecting to http://localhost:8080/login
```

Comment: Can you please show what you can see in the devtools? Is there maybe a redirect? Furthermore, can you try enabling verbose logging for Spring Security and include the logs/output?

Comment: - I think the Get requests are just to import Javascript files. cause I tried again with the working method (use `.permitAll().failureUrl("/login?error")`) and I saw the same two Get requests, the only difference is when using the custom auth failure is that I don't see the param in URL.
Maybe I should delete the part where I mentioned this from my question.
- Sure I'll try.

Comment: @dan1st apparently the problem is caused by the configuration ` .anyRequest().hasRole("USER")` in my filter chain. I don't understand why the filter doesn't block it when using the configuration `.permitAll().failureUrl("/login?error")` instead of `failureHandler(customFailure)`
is there a way to solve it ?

Comment: Does adding `.authorizeHttpRequests().requestMatchers("/login").anyRequest()` solve the problem?

Comment: @dan1st No, cause this will make the login page accessible even when the user is authenticated

Comment: If you don't want that, you can use `.anonymous()` instead of `.anyRequest()`.

Comment: @dan1st authenticated users still can access the page login (I have edited my question and added the code of the filter)

Comment: Make sure your `antMatchers("/login").anonymous()`configuration is before your login configuration.

Comment: @dan1st like this ?
`http.cors().and().csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login").anonymous().and().antMatcher("/**")
   .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/resources/**", "/reset/password").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated()`

Comment: @dan1st the last permitAll() is what made the page accessible for authenticated users `.formLogin()
           .loginPage("/login")
           .successHandler(myAuthenticationSuccessHandler()).failureHandler(customFailure)
     .permitAll()`

Comment: Well, you need to try it and check whether it works.

Comment: add @ControllerAdvice annotation on class CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler .

Comment: @Nidhi257 It didn't work. but it's okay I used the the idaa of dan1st.
Can you please take a look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77258250/how-can-i-prevent-a-user-form-authentication-if-he-has-status-disabled